# Realtime database function triggers constantly

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a JS function for Firebase realtime database triggers. In its operations, it should send a push notification just on value update in the database, which is dead simple:

```
{
 "rollo" : "yes"
}
```

If value changes to yes it should trigger notification. If it goes to "no" then it should do nothing. Here is the JS function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNewPostNotif = functions.database.ref('/rollo').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  console.log('Push notification event triggered');
  const beforeData = change.before.val();

      const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Push triggered!',
            body: "Push text",
            sound: "default"
        }
    };

      const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 10 * 1
    };

  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload, options);
});
```

Also even though I have set TTL, each value change sends another push notification.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, and what's breaking... right now it sends a notification for every change to the DB, not just when it changes to "yes".. but right now it also sends when it changes to "no"... and you don't want that... is that right? I see you have `const beforeData = change.before.val();` but you never do anything with it. So your solution would be a simple `if (beforeData === 'no' && afterData === 'yes')` conditional.... Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @JeremyW You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
exports.sendNewPostNotif = functions.database.ref('/rollo').onWrite((change, context) => {

  const newData = change.after.val();
  const oldData = change.before.val();

      const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Push triggered!',
            body: "Push text",
            sound: "default"
        }
    };

      const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 10 * 1
    };
  if (newData != oldData && newData == 'yes') {
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload, options);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`onUpdate()`:

> triggers when data is updated in the Realtime Database.

When you update it to "no" it will send a notification and when you update it to "yes" it will also send a notification.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events